# PhpStorm Incorrectly Separate WordPress Loop Start Statement into 2 Lines

Tags: php, html, wordpress, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm to development a theme for WordPress. However I have encountered some code reformat problem:

WordPress' loop start with this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

In some files, when I reformat my code by pressing `option` `cmd` `L`, PhpStorm doesn't break it into 2 lines. However in some other files it breaks the statement into 2 lines to this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post(); ?>
```

I don't want PhpStorm to break it into 2 lines.

In my PhpStorm settings, I have chosen:

1. enabled "Keep when reformatting: Control statement in one line";
2. Do not force braces on `if()` statement;
3. Do not force braces on `while()` statement.

I also imported WordPress predefined style setting:
[PhpStorm importing WordPress predefined style setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHU31.jpg)

For reference, here is the file that works fine:

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Left Sidebar
*/
get_header(); ?>
<section class="two-column row no-max pad">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Primary Column -->
            <div class="small-12 medium-7 medium-offset-1 medium-push-4 columns">
                <div class="primary">

                    <!-- The loop starts -->
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <h1><?php the_title( '', '<hr>', true ); ?></h1>
                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                        <!-- The loop stops -->
                    <?php endwhile;
                    else : ?>
                        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no pages found.' ); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Secondary Column -->
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 medium-pull-8 columns">
                <div class="secondary">
                    <h2 class="module-heading">Sidebar</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And here is the file where the statement got broken into 2 lines:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section class="two-column row no-max pad">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Primary Column -->
            <div class="small-12 medium-7 medium-offset-1 medium-push-4 columns">
                <div class="primary">

                    <!-- The loop starts -->
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :
                        the_post(); ?>

                    <article class="post">
                        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                        <h2><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h2>
                        <ul class="post-meta no-bullet">
                            <li class="author">
                                <a href="<?php get_the_author_posts_link(); ?>">
                                    <span
                                        class="wpt-avatar small"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'id' ), 24 ); ?></span>
                                    by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="cat">in <?php the_category(); ?></li>
                            <li class="date">on <?php the_date(); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <?php if ( get_the_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                            <div class="img-container">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                <p>Photo by <?php the_author(); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <!-- The loop stops -->
                        <!-- indentation error -->
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no pages found.' ); ?></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </article>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Secondary Column -->
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 medium-pull-8 columns">
                <div class="secondary">
                    <h2 class="module-heading">Sidebar</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, at the end of the second file, there is also an indentation error: `<?php endwhile; ?>` should be indented 1 block farther than `<?php endif; ?>`, but now they are indented on the same level. I don't know if the 2 problems are related, but they certainly appear together whenever PhpStorm incorrectly breaks 1 statement into 2 lines in a file.

OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Version: PhpStorm 2016.1, Build #PS-145.258, built on March 16, 2016

Here is the google drive link for my settings export file, if anyone wants to try it out:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1315Xx-cq_ObVRGcnZqWWRuVms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why don't you post a bug report?

Comment: Because I didn't know if that's a bug, or just me not using PhpStorm correctly. If other uses think this is a bug, I'll send a bug report.

Comment: Just send a bug report. Guys at intellij care about their products.

Comment: Export your Code Style (`File | Export Settings..`) and share it somewhere. With my settings IDE leaves it on the same line

Comment: Sorry just saw your reply. I have uploaded the setting export file onto Google Drive. Thank you!